# Loading an optional dependency

Tags: java, class, reflection, shared-libraries

I am trying to load a dependency that might not be there at runtime. I have read an  article about [loading strategies](http://axelfontaine.com/blog/optional-dependencies.html). I have now implementation issues. 
My code is currently:

```
// Addition might not be available at runtime
try {
    Class Addition = Class.forName("com.thirdparty.Addition");
    com.thirdparty.Addition addition = (com.thirdparty.Addition)Addition.newInstance();
    int sum = addition.add(4,5);
    System.out.println("The result is: " + sum);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("Addition is not available");
}
```

This code snippet works when the Addition class is available. It does not work when the class is not available:

```
com.thirdparty.Addition cannot be resolved to a type
```

I have read already the javadoc on the [Class.forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) method but I do not really understand how to use it in the real word.

Comment: I assume the error you get is a compile-time error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use reflection to call the add method,like this:

```
try {
    Class Addition = Class.forName("com.thirdparty.Addition");
    Object addition = Addition.newInstance();
    Method addMethod = Addition.getMethod("add", int.class, int.class);
    Integer sum = (Integer)addMethod.invoke(addition, 4, 5);
    System.out.println("The result is: " + sum);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Addition is not available");
}
```

Comment: The better solution is to define an `interface` which is always available and let the optional class implement that interface. Then the extension can be instantiated via Reflection but type-cast to the interface type afterwards. So, further use of the extension can be without the Reflection overhead.